# VHDL subtype constrained by specific values (not range)

Tags: vhdl

Is it possible to constrain a subtype not by a range `x to|downto y`, but instead by specific values or combined ranges, like it is possible with the choices in `case`?

It might look like this:

```vhdl
subtype validValues is integer (0 to 21 | 42 | 1337 | 9001 to integer'high);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dig into the norme of the VHDL 1076-2008 : [http://www.fis.agh.edu.pl/~skoczen/hdl/ieee_std/ieee1076-2008.pdf](http://www.fis.agh.edu.pl/%7Eskoczen/hdl/ieee_std/ieee1076-2008.pdf)

It is not possible in VHDL 2008 (and prior to this standard) to do whay you would like: on paragraph 5.2.3 Integer types:

> An integer type definition defines an integer type whose set of values includes those of the specified range.
>
> ...
>
> An integer type definition defines both a type and a subtype of that type. The type is an anonymous type, the range of which is selected by the implementation; **this range shall be such that it wholly contains the range given in the integer type definition**. The subtype is a named subtype of this anonymous base type, where the name of the subtype is that given by the corresponding type declaration and the **range of the subtype is the
> given range**.

The norm always talk about a *range* of elements, a *list* like you suggest does not seem possible.